# iOS method called before scrollViewDidScroll on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to process scroll event on UITableView before it is processed in scrollViewDidScroll method. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `table.scrollview.delegate` to `self` and override the `scrollviewDidScroll` method. In the method do your processing before calling `[super scrollViewDidScroll]`.

Comment: Can I disable processing [super scrollViewDidScroll] in my overrided method (I dont want to scroll table after I process it in my overriden scrollviewDidScroll method?

Comment: Ya you can do that. Its upto you. You can compensate scrolling by setting the contentOffset in the opposite direction.

Comment: but how can I disable it because I override this method now and its scrolling anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

This is much more convenient.